# Indexed part select synthesizable in verilog

Tags: indexing, verilog, counter, xilinx, synthesis

Can I use something like code below (counter value in vector index) in my verilog code?

```
data_out[cnt*32 + 31 : cnt*32] = data_in;
```

Is this construct synthesizable in xst? I've got a constant defined data_out range and cnt is incremented on clock and never reaches value greater than max range of data_out. Everything else is synchronous to one clk.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure your example will not compile however from Verilog 2001 you can do this:

```
data_out[cnt*32 +: 32] = data_in;
```

Section 5.2.1 in IEEE 1364-2005 Vector bit-select and part-select addressing

Or [Section 7.4.3 of IEEE 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

I am quite confident in saying that you cannot synthesize this with any synthesizer.

As I understand it you want to keep the previous values(of lower indexes) of the output when your counter increments. I do not see how to do it without registers.

In my opinion, a way to do it would be to store each 32bits in registers(enabled by the counter value) and assign to the output the concatenation of these registers.

Answer (score 0):

I think in the above statement: `data_out[cnt*32 + 31 : cnt*32] = data_in;` if `cnt = 0`, it will be `data_out[31:0] = data_in;`.

Also, same statement can be written as `data_out[cnt*32 +: 32] = data_in;` as explained by Morgan.